# Why can't the JS file understand the extension name that I compiled from the TS?

Tags: node.js, typescript

I have a problem with the TS compiled file, the node can't find the module that I distributed from the TS file, and I got a message, "Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module Coding\Telepo\server\dist\Utility\mongo' imported from D:\Coding\Telepo\server\dist\server.js". But I still can click the path from the server.js to mongo.js, and the only way it works is I change my extension name from mongo to mongo.js. So I should rename all the filenames to js files to prevent the node from understanding?

here is my config of TS,

```
 "module": "es2022",
 "moduleResolution": "node",
 "target": "es2021"
```

BTW, I will get the error message, 'An import path can only end with a '.ts' extension when 'allowImportingTsExtensions' is enabled.' when I rename the extension name to mongo.ts". Is the core problem?

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77090080/7028056) answer, that'll give you a clue of what's happening.

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much for explaining that.

Answer (score 0):

When you change the extension of your JavaScript file to Typescript, the **node** doesn't recognize your *.ts* file.

For it to work, you have to install a package to your server directory and restart the server:

```
npm i ts-node
```